# $\kappa$-categoricity in the language of identity

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have the following exercise from Dirk Van Dalen's Logic and Structure:

[image]

Here with language of identity we mean the language with no extralogical symbols (i.e. no symbols of predicates, functions or constants), the $=$ being a logical symbol.
Formulas $I_1, I_2, I_3$ are the axioms for the equivalence relation, i.e. respectively

$$ I_1 := \forall x (x=x)\\ I_2 := \forall xy (x=y \rightarrow y=x) \\ I_3 := \forall xyz(x=y \land  y=z \rightarrow x=z) $$

My doubt is: being the language so simple, an isomorphism is just a bijection, so how it is possible that the theory is not $\aleph_0$-categorical? Aren't two countable sets necessarily in bijection?

Comment: You are forgetting about the constants, they are indeed in the language and must be respected by isos.

Comment: Sure, but the constant are countable and $\Gamma$ is enforcing their interpretation to be different, this should just mean that there are at least a countable number of different elements. I am probably missing some basic thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: For the countable case, think along these lines: Is every element in your domain named by one of the constants? What happens if they are not?

Edit1: Further to your comment; suppose that every element of $M\models{T}$ is named by one of the constants and $N\models{T}$ has exactly one element that is not named by the constants (here $M$, $N$ are countable). Now consider any bijection $f$ between them. Now use the definition of $L$ isomorphism to show that $f$ is not an L-isomorphism (You say that you think any bijection is an L-isomorphism. This is not true).

Comment: I tried to reason in that direction, sorry if I'm saying something trivially wrong: of course $\Gamma$ does not imply that every element in my domain is the interpretation of $c_i$ for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$ - we can simply consider a domain having an element for each $c_i$, plus another one, or other two, or other countably many. At the same time, however, if the domain remains countable there should always be a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$…or not?

Comment: Yes. There is a bijection, but the bijection will not be an $L$ isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much, as I supposed I was trivially wrong...